# Best way to build a hierarchy CLI menu?

Tags: object-oriented, cli

I want to build a command line interface with menus and sub-menus and eventually the leafs of the tree should be operations like..
bank management -> account management -> add acount (insert account info)
And I'm looking for a good way which works with the OO principles...

Thanks for any piece of advice!

Comment: navigating a CLI can be seen as traversing a state machine, with each state a menu and the edges the commands at each menu

Comment: yeah..but should do it with a while loop? or what..im stuck with it

Comment: I tried making a "menunude" abstract class which has the sub classes menu and operation..menu has a list of menus and operation has an execute function which does whatever it's supposed to do...the problem is what to put in the main thingy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want OO I suggest a Menu interface with methods to write out the options and parsing the input and returning the next Menu

so your main loop becomes:

```
Menu menu = new StartMenu();
    while(menu.isExit){
    menu.writeOptions(stdOut);
    Menu res = menu.parseInput(stdIn.readline());
    if(res==null)
        writeError(stdOut);
    else
        menu=res;
}
```

Comment: But what If I want to encapsulate the whole loop inside a seperate menu class,How should I do that?

Comment: You could put this code inside a static method in the base class if you really wanted to. Call it RunMenu().